# Question over 'Russia warned of 'consequences' if Navalny dies.'

Tags: headlinese

I read BBC news today, and this title 'Russia warned of 'consequences' if Navalny dies.' made me confused.

The news says the U.S warned Russia of 'consequences' if Navalny dies. My question is why the title does not have 'is' (Russia *is* warned of 'consequences' if Navalny dies.) for the passive form. Then I searched some answers online, someone explains 'Russia warned of 'consequences' is not a completed sentence. Therefore, the title does not need to use 'is' for the passive form.

If anyone can confirm this explanation, and why this sentence is not a completed sentence.

Comment: _Many_ people have asked questions here about 'headlinese' - the abbreviated English used in newspaper headlines. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280197/headlines-of-any-news-articles/280238#280238 or look up 'headlinese'.

Answer (score 1):

The intended meaning of this headline

> 'Russia warned of 'consequences' if Navalny dies.'

is indeed

> Russia [*Auxiliary_verb*] warned of 'consequences' if Navalny dies.

Headline writers, however, have their constraints and hence use a different set of rules.

Headlines 'are meant to succinctly convey what is in the story in a way that is compelling enough to motivate readers'.

There is a different set of rules to use 'in order to fit story toppers[, which are often in large font,] into sometimes impossibly tight spaces'.

For concision, 'writers of newspaper headlines are...inveterate sweepers away of little words'.

[https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921#:~:text=Why%20Headlines%20Are%20Almost%20Never%20Sentences&text=Dr.&text=Headlinese%20is%20an%20informal%20term,%2Dtense%20verbs%2C%20and%20ellipsis](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921#:%7E:text=Why%20Headlines%20Are%20Almost%20Never%20Sentences&text=Dr.&text=Headlinese%20is%20an%20informal%20term,%2Dtense%20verbs%2C%20and%20ellipsis)